# Por que no desaparece el punto y el guiaon bajo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola quiero que desaparesca el siguiente o los carasteres especiales de cualquier tipo  de aqui

```
DECLARE @CharName varchar (50) = 'Mino_.shut',
@new varchar (50)

SET @new = (SELECT replace(@CharName,'%[^a-z_A-Z.0-9-]%',''))

SELECT @new
```

QUe esta mal de ese Script

Comment: ¿Cuáles serían los caracteres especiales? ¿Cómo esperas que sea la salida de tu ejemplo?

Comment: todos los especiales osea todo lo que no sea de la A a la Z y del 0 al 9

Answer (score 1):

Por más que en la documentación de [`replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) se habla de *string_pattern* como parámetro de reemplazo, en realidad éste no maneja ningún patrón especial, sino, simplemente recibe una cadena de reemlazo de la otra a buscar, por lo que deberías usar alguna otra alternativa para lo que preguntas.

#### 1. Mediante una tabla de caracteres a remover

Si creas previamente una tabla de cadenas o caracteres a remover, puedes utilizarla para aplicar  el `replace()` sobre la variable:

```
DECLARE @CharName varchar (50) = 'Mino_.shut'

declare @Remove table (
    StringToRemove varchar(100) not null primary key clustered
)
-- Tabla de caracteres a remover
insert into @Remove (StringToRemove)
    values ('_'),('.')

select @CharName = replace(@CharName, StringToRemove, '')
      from @Remove

select @CharName --< Minoshut
```

---

#### 2. Iterar y reemplazar cada caracter

Usando `patindex()`, podemos usar un patrón pero sobre cada caracter de la cadena, aunque los ciclos explícitos no suele ser lo más óptimo, al menos resulta una solución cómoda ya que simplemente podemos definir un patrón de letras y números negados para ubicar los caracteres a remover:

```
DECLARE @CharName VARCHAR(100) = 'Mino_!.shut'
DECLARE @pattern VARCHAR(100) = '%[^0-9A-z]%';
DECLARE @i INT;
BEGIN
  SET @i = PATINDEX(@pattern,@CharName) 
  WHILE @i <> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @CharName = LEFT(@CharName,@i-1) + '' + SUBSTRING(@CharName,@i+1,100);
    SET @i = PATINDEX(@pattern,@CharName) 
  END
  SELECT @CharName;
END;
```

---

#### 3. SQLServer 2017 o superior - [translate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775084.aspx)

Usando esta función, puedes definir en una cadena los caracteres a remover y en otra de igual longitud, los caracteres de reemplazo, unificamos todos estos en un solo caracter y lLuego si con `replace()` los eliminamos.

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE('Mino_.shut', '_.','  '), ' ', '')
```

---

#### 4. SQLServer 2016 o superior - [`string_split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Con esta función podemos armar una cadena de caracteres a eliminar (separados por espacio o algún otro separador) y transformarla en una tabla, para realizar un remplazo por cada caracter:

```
DECLARE @CharName varchar (50) = 'Mino_.shut'
DECLARE @remove_chars varchar(255) = '. _'

Select 
   @CharName = Replace(@CharName, value, '') 
From 
   String_Split(@remove_chars,' ')
   
select @CharName
```

---

#### 5. `PatExclude8K()` de Michael Colling

Dentro de las posibilidad de resolver el problema mediante una función "ad hoc", creo que la más óptima es esta, aunque siempre estará limitada a cadenas de hasta 8k.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatExclude8K
(
    @String VARCHAR(8000),
    @Pattern VARCHAR(50)
) 
/*******************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Given a string (@String) and a pattern (@Pattern) of characters to remove, 
 remove the patterned characters from the string.

Usage:
--===== Basic Syntax Example
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.PatExclude8K(@String,@Pattern);

--===== Remove all but Alpha characters
 SELECT CleanedString 
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^A-Za-z]%');

--===== Remove all but Numeric digits
 SELECT CleanedString
 FROM dbo.SomeTable st
 CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(st.SomeString,'%[^0-9]%');

 Programmer Notes:
 1. @Pattern is not case sensitive (the function can be easily modified to make it so)
 2. There is no need to include the "%" before and/or after your pattern since since we 
    are evaluating each character individually

 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 10/27/2014 Initial Development - Alan Burstein

 Rev 01 - 10/29/2014 Mar 2007 - Alan Burstein
        - Redesigned based on the dbo.STRIP_NUM_EE by Eirikur Eiriksson
          (see: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1585850-391-2.aspx)
        - change how the cte tally table is created 
        - put the include/exclude logic in a CASE statement instead of a WHERE clause
        - Added Latin1_General_BIN Colation
        - Add code to use the pattern as a parameter.

 Rev 02 - 11/6/2014
        - Added final performane enhancement (more cudo's to Eirikur Eiriksson)
        - Put 0 = PATINDEX filter logic into the WHERE clause

Rev 03 - 5/16/2015
        - Updated code to deal with special XML characters
*******************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH
E1(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) AS X(N)),
itally(N) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP(CONVERT(INT,LEN(@String),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM E1 T1 CROSS JOIN E1 T2 CROSS JOIN E1 T3 CROSS JOIN E1 T4
) 
SELECT NewString =
((
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,N,1)
  FROM iTally
  WHERE 0 = PATINDEX(@Pattern,SUBSTRING(@String COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'));
```

Y la ejecución:

```
DECLARE @CharName varchar (50) = 'Mino_.shut'

SELECT NewString 
       FROM dbo.PatExclude8K(@CharName,'%[^A-Za-z0-9]%');
```

---

Fuentes:

- [How to Replace Multiple Characters in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580017/how-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-sql)

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee0ddf6091dc5cd6fbc76689a26e7d13)